# Database design - How to relate a table to two others in a unique way?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm having trouble designing a database where one table can be related to two other tables uniquely.

I have three tables.

**Groups**

```
id_group, name, contact_id
```

**Products**

```
id_product, id_group, name, contact_id
```

**Contacts**

```
contact_id, phone
```

Each product can be independent or belong to a group. In the case of belonging to a group, the product inherits the group contact.

The first problem is that a contact has to be unique and can only relate to the group table or the product table, but not both at the same time.

The second problem is how do I replace the product contact with the group contact if the product belongs to a group using an sql query.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Could it be as simple as a CHECK on `Products` enforcing that only `id_group` or `contact_id` is NOT NULL, but not both? You'd then (in your business logic) interpret a NULL `Products.contact_id` as having to look-up the `Groups.contact_id`, which could be neatly encapsulated in a view.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem isn't straightforward to solve using logic in the database. You might be better off doing that validation at application level.

The second question is much easier, although depends on the flavour of SQL you are using. either of following would work in MySQL and T-SQL:

```
-- This way might be slower since the optimizer wouldn't know which contact_id index to  use but would be ok on smallish tables.
SELECT 
    p.id_product,
    p.id_group,
    p.name,
    c.*
FROM 
    Products p
LEFT JOIN 
    Groups g
ON 
    p.id_group = g.id_group
INNER JOIN
    Contact c
ON
    COALESCE(p.contact_id, g.contact_id) = c.contact_id;


-- This is a bit more long winded, but might be quicker to run on larger tables
-- as long as your indexes are setup right
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 
    p.id_product,
    p.id_group,
    p.name,
    c.*
FROM 
    Products p
INNER JOIN 
    Groups g
ON 
    p.id_group = g.id_group
INNER JOIN
    Contact c
ON
    g.contact_id = c.contact_id
UNION
SELECT 
    p.id_product,
    p.id_group,
    p.name,
    c.*
FROM 
    Products p
INNER JOIN
    Contact c
ON
    p.contact_id = c.contact_id
WHERE 
    p.id_group IS NULL) AS t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by listing the relationships between contacts, groups, and products.

- A contact can have many groups or products.
- A group can have many contacts.
- A group can have many products.
- A product can belong to zero or one group.
- A product can have many contacts.

When you have a many to many relationship, you use a junction table to make the connection.

Let's define the Contact, Group, and Product tables.

```
Contact
-------
Contacj ID
Contact Name
Contacy Address
Contact Telephone
Contact Email
...

Group
-----
Group IG
Group Name

Product
-------
Product ID
Product Name
Group ID (FK)
```

With these tables, the contact information is in one place, the Cibtact table.

Now, let's create a junction table to tie the Contacts and Groups together.

```
ContactGroup
------------
ContactGroupID
Contact ID
Group ID
```

There's a unique index on (Contact ID, Group ID).  You can also have a unique index on (Group ID, Contact ID).

Here's the junction table for Contact and Product.

```
ContactProduct
--------------
ContactProduct ID
Contact ID
Product ID
```

There's a unique index on (Contact ID, Product ID).  You can also have a unique index on (Product ID, Contact ID).

It's up to your application to determine which junction table to add an association row.